# Is my own proof of the Extreme Value Theorem correct?

Tags: analysis

I came up with my own version of the proof of the Extreme Value Theorem. The **bounded part** of the theorem that the range of any continuous function defined on a closed bounded interval is bounded is OK to me. But I wonder if my proof of the part that the range has its supremum and infimum is correct. Here's my proof.

Let $C$ be a closed bounded interval, $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Since $f$ is a continuous function defined on a closed bounded interval, $f(C)$ is bounded. By the complentess of $\mathbb{R}$, $f(C)$ has the supremum, say $M$. Suppose $M$ is not in $f(C)$, then $\forall y\in f(C), f(C)<M$. Let $z\in C$, then there exists a $\delta_z$ such that $\forall x\in C,|x-z|<\delta_z\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(z)|<\frac{M-f(z)}{2}$. Hence the  $f(z)+\frac{M-f(z)}{2}$, which is less than $M$, is an upper bound of $f((z-\delta_z,z+\delta_z))$. So $M$ is not the supremum of $f((z-\delta_z,z+\delta_z))$. We let $M_z$ be its supremum.

On the other hand, it is obvious that $\{(z-\delta_z,z+\delta_z)|z\in C\}$ is an open covering of $C$. By the Heine-Borel theorem, there exists a finite covering  $\mathcal{O}_1,\mathcal{O}_2,\dotsc,\mathcal{O}_n$ such that $C\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}}\mathcal{O}_i$. Let $M^*=\max\{M_1,M_2,\dotsc,M_n\}$, and notice that $M^*<M$.
Let $x\in C$, then $x\in \bigcup_{i\in\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}}\mathcal{O}_i$. Then there exists an $i\in\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ such that $x\in\mathcal{O}_i$, then $f(x)\leq M_i\leq M^*<M$, hence $M^*$ is an upper bound of $f(C)$. Therefore $M$ is not the supremum of $f(C)$, a contradiction. So, $M$ is in $f(C)$. The proof of the infimum is the same.

Comment: Seems ok (there is a small typo in the beginning $y<M$ rather than $f(C)<M$). For the existence of  $\delta_z>0$ it would be reasonable to invoke continuity of $f$. It is easier to work with sequences but I suppose you know this.

Comment: For me, it's correct.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part :) To me the key argument is that $f(x)$ is arbitrary close to $M$, so there is a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) \to M$, extract a convergent subsequence $y_k$ from $x_n$ (since $C$ is compact, it exists) and you get $y_k \to y, f(y_k) \to M$, i.e. by continuity $f(y) = M$